Is it possible to execute multiple CI/CD components on a Gitlab pipeline?
Our team is creating a CI/CD component project for running common deployment tasks.  In this scenario, we have a component called terraform that inits and applies terraform code.
Here's how our main pipeline code looks like.
# .gitlab-ci.yml
stages:
- deploy

deploy-environment-alpha:
  stage: deploy
  include:
  - local: path/to/deploy.yml
# Trigger downstream pipeline with component(s)
trigger-downstream-pipeline:
  stage: triggers
  trigger:
    include:
      - local: path/to/deploy.yml
    strategy: depend

#### Additional CD triggers ...

Given the contents below for path/to/deploy.yml, the pipeline works as expected. It triggers the child pipeline and imports the component.
# path/to/deploy.yml
include:
- component: /path/to/terraform@1.0.0
  inputs:
    job-name: deploy-alpha
    job-stage: deploy
    foo: alpha

Now, I want to update the deploy.yml to include two components.
# path/to/deploy.yml
include:
- component: /path/to/terraform@1.0.0
  inputs:
    job-name: deploy-alpha
    job-stage: deploy
    foo: alpha

# path/to/deploy.yml
include:
- component: /path/to/terraform@1.0.0
  inputs:
    job-name: deploy-beta
    job-stage: deploy
    foo: beta

For some reason, Gitlab is only showing the deploy-alpha job.  Any reason why it is ignoring deploy-beta?

The include keyword is global and as such does not belong to any job. To be honest I'm surprised that your actual setup does work as the include keyword is not supposed to be used within a job, as the docs specify:

Keyword type: Global keyword.

That said, I think that what you want to achieve can be done in a different way. Given a sample component:
spec:
  inputs:
    foo:
      default: alpha
---
deploy-environment-alpha:
  stage: $[[ inputs.foo ]]
  script: echo "Deploy alpha"

deploy-environment-beta:
  stage: $[[ inputs.foo ]]
  script: echo "Deploy beta"

Then you can reference it multiple times like this in your yaml file:
stages: [alpha, beta]

include:
  - component: /path/to/terraform@1.0.0
    inputs:
      foo: alpha
  - component: /path/to/terraform@1.0.0
    inputs:
      foo: beta



The key was having a single include keyword with all the items listed.  Thanks for your help!

@Byob all the items listed.  ? how-to references sh file in a component from another project-component ?
